# How can I pre select an option from a drop down field via URL?

Tags: excel, url, select, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am trying to preselect a dropdown option on a website via the URL and just can't seem to find the correct syntrax.

The Website is this - https://basketballmonster.com/playerrankings.aspx

What I would like is to be able to open the website and that the Filters option of "Only Top Players" be changed to "All Players" via the URL.
I tried so many options using ID, xpath and so on but can't seem to find the correct syntax for it to load the page with the "All Players" option pre-selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Which language are you using? Python, for example?

Comment: No language, via the URL.

Comment: For example, I tried the following - https://basketballmonster.com/playerrankings.aspx?PlayerFilterControl=All%20Players as I saw in another site that it worked, but didn't for my site. I wonder if its' because its' aspx.